# Why does jQuery's .on() work but native JavaScript's .addEventListener() doesn't?

Tags: javascript, jquery, woocommerce, event-handling, dom-events

I need to listen to WooCommerce's custom events like `wc_fragment_refresched` or `added_to_cart`. But when creating a listener for those events via the native `addEventListener` nothing happens. But jQuery's `.on()` works fine.

Working:

```js
jQuery(document.body).on('wc_fragments_refreshed', function() {
  console.log("hehey!");
});
```

Not working:

```js
document.body.addEventListener('wc_fragments_refreshed', function() {
  console.log("hoho!");
});
```

Does anyone have a clue why the native listener isn't working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is because `addEventListener()` doesn't listen for events triggered by jQuery. For that event handler to be raised you need to use `dispatchEvent` on `document.body`.

Below is an example. Note that jQuery fires twice because it *does* handle both event triggers.

```js
// jQuery
$(document.body).on('wc_fragments_refreshed', function() {
  console.log("jQuery handled the event");
}).trigger('wc_fragments_refreshed');

// Native
document.body.addEventListener('wc_fragments_refreshed', function() {
  console.log("POJS handled the event");
});
document.body.dispatchEvent(new Event('wc_fragments_refreshed'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```